# Flex как выровнять по верху контейнера

Tags: html5, css3, flexbox

```css
  body{
   background:#FFF;
  }
  *{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
  }
  .wrapper{
   display:inline-flex;
   height:auto;
   margin:auto;
   min-height:120px;
   width:33%;
   box-shadow:0 0 5px #ccc;
   flex-direction:column;
  }
  .wrapper div{
   width:auto;
   display:flex;
   align-content:space-between;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   height:auto;
   padding:0;
   background:#ccc;
   margin-bottom:3px;
  }
  .wrapper div img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:840px) {
    body{
      background:#FFF;
    }
    .wrapper{
    width:49%;
    display:inline-flex;
    }
    .wrapper div{
     margin:auto;
   }
  }
  @media screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:480px) {
    body{
      background:#FFF;
    }
    .wrapper{
    width:100%;
    display:inline-flex;
    } 
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrapper"> 
            <div class="images"><img src="http://you-zone.com/_files/photo/101573_1116366_b.jpg" alt="" /></div>   
            <div class="images"><img src="http://novoston.com/sites/default/files/news_img/user83/main_original.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://wallpaper.getwall.ru/25/preview/76140.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://wallpaper.getwall.ru/25/preview/76140.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>   
            <div class="images"><img src="http://novoston.com/sites/default/files/news_img/user83/main_original.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://you-zone.com/_files/photo/101573_1116366_b.jpg" alt="" /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper"> 
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://novoston.com/sites/default/files/news_img/user83/main_original.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://you-zone.com/_files/photo/101573_1116366_b.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://novoston.com/sites/default/files/news_img/user83/main_original.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://you-zone.com/_files/photo/101573_1116366_b.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://wallpaper.getwall.ru/25/preview/76140.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://wallpaper.getwall.ru/25/preview/76140.jpg" alt="" /></div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="images"><img src="http://novoston.com/sites/default/files/news_img/user83/main_original.jpg" alt="" /></div> 
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://you-zone.com/_files/photo/101573_1116366_b.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://you-zone.com/_files/photo/101573_1116366_b.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://wallpaper.getwall.ru/25/preview/76140.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://novoston.com/sites/default/files/news_img/user83/main_original.jpg" alt="" /></div>   
            <div class="images"><img src="http://4risk.net/_pliki_/zdjecia/12012914952892.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="images"><img src="http://wallpaper.getwall.ru/25/preview/76140.jpg" alt="" /></div>   
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ни как вложенные блоки не выравниаются по самому верху flex-контейнера , как выровнять ?

Answer (score 1):

Вашему врапперу дайте свойство justify-content: flex-start. Если нужно просто прижать дочерние элементы вверх. Если нужно чтобы первый блок начинался от верха а остальные распределялись равномерно то justify-content: space-between врапперу. То же самое нужно сделать и с дочерними дивами, чтобы разместить изображения.

Comment: не помогло это - я так делал , я и родителю (wrapper) присвоил это свойство и вложенным блокам - как было так и осталось

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под выровнять по верху контейнера? Ваш пример прижат к верху.

Comment: http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=62e3a85f674a616862f299ad9689ec4f   вот посмотрите я чёрными стрелками показал

Comment: Ха) так картинки у вас в строку идут. Flex-direction: row поставьте. И align-items: flex-start. Для контейнера display:flex;. Все остальные свойства, связанные с flexbox уберите

Comment: ни чего не изменилось - у меня там два контейнера -

Comment: на яндэкс на сервисе картинок , у них там все картинки разных размеров и идут с определённым смещением но ровненько (http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=ef3ba967d19c40531dac5eea347e1edd) вот это эффект не знаю как добиться